# How to disable/enable panning in Google Street View Panorama?

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I am having trouble trying to disable panning on google street view panorama for my app. I've looked at the Street View's documentation and couldn't find any ways to do it. Is it even possible to do this? Thanks~

Comment: Is this for a web app or a mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

This is working as intended as panoramas are essentially long pan-able images.

I suggest using Street View Static API instead to get stills of the same photosphere.

For exampl, this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g37Lh50r/) can also be achieved through Street View Static.

Fiddle Street View code :

```
  var fenway = {lat: 42.345573, lng: -71.098326};
  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('pano'), {
        position: fenway,
        pov: {
          heading: 160,
          pitch: 10
        },
        clickToGo : false,
        panControl: false
      });
```

Static StreetView query :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=800x600&location=42.345573,-71.098326&heading=160&pitch=10&YOUR_API_KEY